# How the Feynman trick works for any incident momentum in loop integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

Currently I'm trying to make careful treatment on every techniques in loop integral. But I have troublesome with using Feynman tricks in loop integral, which is
$$ \frac{1}{A_{1} \cdots A_{n}} = \int{dF_{n}\frac{1}{\left(x_{1}A_{1} + \cdots + x_{n}A_{n} \right)^{n}}}$$
where I borrowed the notation from Srednicki's book, so that,
$$ \int{dF_{n}} = (n-1)!\int_{\left[ 0,1 \right]^{n}}{dx_{1}\cdots dx_{n} \delta\left( 1- \sum_{i}{x_{i}} \right)}.$$

As far as I know, this trick is proved by using $\Gamma$-function, since,
$$ \Gamma(z) \frac{1}{A^{z}} = \int_{0}^{\infty}{dx x^{z-1}e^{-Ax}}.$$
Here my question begins. How can we use $\Gamma$-function to prove Feynman's trick even though the propagator is not strictly positive definite.

If $n=2$, so that it is nothing but $\frac{1}{AB}$, I think we could write another proof using
$$ \frac{1}{(A-i \epsilon)(B-i\epsilon)} = \frac{1}{A-B}\int_{B-i\epsilon}^{A-i\epsilon}{\frac{dz}{z^{2}}} = \int_{0}^{1}{\frac{d \zeta}{\left((A-i\epsilon)\zeta + (B-i\epsilon)(1- \zeta) \right)^{2}}},$$
and I can avoid issue of the sign of propagator, since $\frac{1}{z^{2}}$ is analytic function while we can take pass from $B-i\epsilon$ to $A-i\epsilon$ without passing $0 \in \mathbf{C}^{2}$.

I did not check whether I could find similar proof for arbitrary $n$ or not. But I'm quite sure I should not use $\Gamma$-function to prove Feynman's trick as I wrote above, and I think it still has subtlety even I consider the $-i\epsilon$ contribution for every propagator.

Actually if we performed the Wick's rotation before using Feynman's trick, then all propagators are assured to be positive-definite. but using Wick's rotation before introducing Feynman's trick requires to specify all poles of $l^{0}$, where $l$ is loop-momentum, and I really don't want to do that. If it were possible, I want to use Feynman's trick before Wick's rotation.

And Here is my question.

How could we use Feynman's trick before Wick's rotation even though propagators are not positive definite?

Comment: The gamma function proof for negative $A$ works by analytic continuation.  Since $1/(A_1\ldots A_n)$ is infinitely differentiable in kinematic variables everywhere (except at isolated points), any integral representation you write for it that is valid in some region of finite extent is enough to represent it everywhere (except at those isolated points).

Comment: Is that what you mentioned as isolated points, the external kinematic variables where the corresponding diagram has vanishing value?

Comment: No, I mean the isolated points where $1/A_1\ldots A_n$ is divergent, like when $p^2 = m^2$.